# Google Places API autocomplete not working in MVC 4 Project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

I have struggled with the below code for several hours now. I can't seem to figure out why this code works fine if I put it in a normal .html file, however when creating an MVC4 project in Visual Studio with only an index.cshtml view (containing the same code), no layout, no external javascript or css files, the autocomplete drop down does not pop up.

When I inspect the .pac-container element it has display set to none. I have tried setting the z-index of this element to 1050/10000 in my css like other threads have suggested with no luck. This is the code contained in my html body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = places.getPlace();

            for (var component in componentForm) {
              document.getElementById(component).value = '';
              document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
              var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
              if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
              }
            }
        });
    });

    var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

</script>
<span>Location:</span>
<input type="text" id="txtPlaces" style="width: 250px" placeholder="Enter a location" />

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Province</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Postal Code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"id="country"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My header tag only contains a title.

Any ideas why this does not work in my MVC4 project but works fine in a .html standalone file?

Comment: you are missing the API-key(it's required now for new applications)

Comment: I am using an API-key, I was avoiding posting it here. And I am sure that is not the issue because this works fine in a standalone html file. Try it.

Comment: can you post a link?

Comment: Which link are you looking?

Comment: a link to the page that didn't work as expected

Comment: There is no page you can access. Just simply paste the code I provided in between html body tags and open the file in a browser

Comment: It's not a matter of the code(the code for me works fine with a valid key). Valid key means: valid referer(when set ) and activated APIs: Google Maps Javascript API + Google Places API Webservice

Comment: Found the issue, I did not enable my key in the google API manager. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.